# Which plasmid can express T7 RNA polymerase in mammalian cells?

Tags: plasmids, polymerase, t7-promoter

Does anyone know what plasmid could express T7 RNA polymerase in mammalian cells, I would like to transfect it with other plasmid containing Gene Of Interest under control of T7 promoter. Thanks a lot!